# Keras syntax error for model.add(Dense, (133))

Tags: python, syntax, keras, jupyter

I'm new to Python and deep learning and stuck on this syntax error in my currrent Udacity project.  There are 133 classifications so I put that as the output.  Anyways, please refer to my code below and let me know why I might be getting this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-2979a000d526>", line 18
    model.add(Dense(133))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, strides=(2,2), padding='valid', activation='relu', 
                        input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))# putput of (224,224,16)
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))#output of (112,112,16)
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, strides=(2,2), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
#output is (112,112,32)
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))#output is (56,56,32)
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
#output is (56,56,64)
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))#output is (28,28,64)
#add global average pooling 2D layer 
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format = channels_last)
# don't need to flatten after GAP model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(133)) #error is here
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

### TODO: Define your architecture.

model.summary()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format = channels_last)
```

is missing a parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks bro!  I've been sleeping in my car and caught a cold so my head is a bit cloudy.